# python, search .txt file and inject character

Tags: python, string, search, text

I apologize for my ignorance of how python handles strings in advance. I have a .txt file that is at least 1000 lines long. It looks something like below

```
:dodge
1 6 some description string of unknown length
E7 8 another description string 
3445 0 oil temp something description voltage over limit etc

:ford
AF 4 description of stuff
0 8 string descritiopn
```

What I want to do is basically put a ";" before each string so what I will end up with is as follows

```
:dodge
1 6 ;some description string of unknown length
E7 8 ;another description string 
3445 0 ;oil temp something description voltage over limit etc

:ford
AF 4 ;description of stuff
0 8 ;string descritiopn
```

My idea is to open the file, search for ":" character, next line, goto " " character, goto next " " character and write a ";". Another thought was goto "/n" character in text file if next charachter != ":" then look for second space
    import sys
    import fileinput

```
with open("testDTC.txt", "r+") as f:
for line in f:
    if ' ' in line:     #read first space
        if ' ' in line:     #read second space
            line.append(';')

    f.write(line)

f.close()
```

I know its not close to getting what I need but its been a really long time since I did string manipulation in python.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `if` statements read from files?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist where did you get the idea the the if statement was reading from a file? The if statement is testing a string. Your comment is not particularly useful for the OP. Just snarky.

Comment: Do the strings you want to append with a ; ever begin with numbers themselves?

Comment: Looking at the pattern I would go for a slightly different logic.
I would go for inserting a ; the first time you see a small case alphabet in every line that doesn't start with : (lines are seperated with \n)

Comment: @moorej Oh, I dunno. From the comments in the original code next to if statements that say "read x space"? Anyway there was supposed to be more to that but I got called away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to split  twice on whitespace and join the string, you don't need a regex for a simple repeating pattern:

```
with open("testDTC.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith(":"):
            spl = line.split(None,2)
            print("{} ;{}".format(" ".join(spl[:2]),spl[2]))
```

To write the changes to the original file you can use `fileinput.input` with `inplace=True`:

```
from fileinput import input
for line in input("testDTC.txt",inplace=True):
    if line.strip() and not line.startswith(":"):
        spl = line.split(None,2)
        print("{} ;{}".format(" ".join(spl[:2]),spl[2]),end="")
    else:
        print(line,end="")
```

Instead of indexing we can unpack:

```
        a, b, c = line.split(None,2)
        print("{} {} ;{}".format(a, b, c),end="")
```

Output:

```
:dodge
1 6 ;some description string of unknown length
E7 8 ;another description string 
3445 0 ;oil temp something description voltage over limit etc

:ford
AF 4 ;description of stuff
0 8 ;string descritiopn
```

For python 2 you can remove the `end=""` and use a commas after the print statement instead i.e `print(line),`

We avoid the starting paragraph lines with `line.startswith(":")` and  the empty lines with `if line.strip()`.

Comment: "You don't need a regex for a simple repeating pattern" is exactly right.

Comment: I should add for any others looking into a similar problem that print is handled different between python 2.x and 3.x .... The above works beautifully on 3.x but "print" behaves differently in 2.x and will not recognize end=""

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a pretty simple algorithm without invoking regular expressions so you can see what's going on.

```
with open('test.txt') as infile:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if not line or line.startswith(':'):   # Blank or : line
                outfile.write(line or '\n')        # pass it through
            else:
                line_parts = line.split(None, 2)   # split at most twice
                try:
                    # try adding the semicolon after the 2nd space
                    line_parts[2] = ';' + line_parts[2]
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                outfile.write(' '.join(line_parts))
```

If you actually want to read characters in a file one at a time, you end up using the `read` method along with `seek`, but that is unnecessary in Python since you have high-level constructs like file iteration and powerful string methods to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it seems that in your second column you have a number or numbers separated by spaces, e.g. `8`, `6` followed by some description in third colum which seem not to have any numbers. If this is the case in general, not only for this example, you can use this fact to search for the number separated by the spaces and add `;` after it as follows:

import re

```
rep = re.compile(r'(\s\d+\s)')    

out_lines = []

with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:      
        re_match = rep.search(line)
        if re_match:
            # append ; after the found expression.                         
            line = line.replace(re_match.group(1), re_match.group(1)+';')        
        out_lines.append(line)



with open('file2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(out_lines)
```

The file2.txt obtained is as follows:

```
:dodge
1 6 ;some description string of unknown length
E7 8 ;another description string
3445 0 ;oil temp something description voltage over limit etc

:ford
AF 4 ;description of stuff
0 8 ;string descritiopn
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
for line in f:
    if ' ' in line:
        sp = line.split(' ', 2)
        line = '%s %s ;%s' % (sp[0], sp[1], sp[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 1000 lines or so, I think you can get away with readling it all at once with readlines() and using split for each line.  If the line has only one element then print it, then call another loop that treats following lines with more than one element and replaces the third [2] element with the concatenation of the semicolon and the element.  Then you have to do something to output the line nicely (here with join, but lots of other solutions for that) depending on what you want with it.

```
with open('testDTC.txt') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

for i in xrange(len(lines)):
    if len(lines[i].split()) == 1:
        print lines[i][:-1]
        i += 1
        while len(lines[i].split()) > 0:
            spl = lines[i].split()
            spl[2] = ";"+spl[2]
            print " ".join(spl)
            i += 1
            if i == len(lines):
                break
        print
```